# How to setTimeout() with a jQuery function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

`setTimeout(target.mousedown, 200)` doesn't seem to work. I can do `setTimeout("target.mousedown()", 200)`, but this feels dirty.

What's the right way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might like this better:

```
setTimeout(function() { target.mousedown(); }, 200);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use an anonymous function:

```
setTimeout(function () {
  target.mousedown();
}, 200);
```

And you're right, you should always [avoid](http://www.jslint.com/lint.html#evil) using string parameters in setTimeout and setInterval functions.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't given us too much of your code but this definitely works:

```
var target = {
    mousedown: function() {
        alert('foo');
    }
};

setTimeout(target.mousedown, 200);
```